# How to send mail from local for development?

Tags: php, smtp, web

I am using XAMPP for local development and I am using the mail() function for sending the mail. But unfortunately it won't send the mail. I am not using any SMTP server in localhost. If I need to send mail what can I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When I develop components sending e-mails, I use [smtp-sink](http://www.postfix.org/smtp-sink.1.html) (part of Postfix distribution). It's a test SMTP server that does not transmit mails, but dumps them.

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably better suited to Stackoverflow but you can use a mock SMTP server like [fakemail](http://www.lastcraft.com/fakemail.php).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[sSMTP](http://www.scottro.net/qnd/qnd-ssmtp.html) is one option, node.js SMTP server is another. Fakemail as mentioned by HTTP500 is definitely an option. You can configure sendmail to send outbound emails only, there are lots of options here.

You haven't really specified what OS you're using, etc.

You can also send through Gmail, see this post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)